# Window hierarchy ios

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a question that probably already has been answered but I just can't find it.

I have a view that calls some webservice and when the result comes back I want to open another view to present the result. Right after the call to WS I close that window.

Now my problem is that when I try to open it with presentViewController with

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.visibleViewController!.presentViewController or
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.visibleViewController!.childViewControllers[0].presentViewController
```

the same is if I access to rootViewControler.

I get the error that the view is not in the hierarchy any more since it already called viewWillDisappear.

So is there any way to show a view over all views no matter what is the current top view?

EDIT:

The solution was really ugly and stupid. I have a static variable which gets changed every time viewDidApear is called to that view. This way I have the last view that is shown. I know this isn't good way to do it or maybe even not safe way, but I don't have any other idea.

Comment: plz show some more code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to show ViewController on top of another, but for this you should not touch your window at all.
In your view controller class right after your call completed call

```
let viewController = ViewController() //change this to your view controller class that you want to present
self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: In normal case this works, the problem is that on the window that I call this is not a UIViewController and so I have to get the apps top view.

Answer (score 0):

Call web service and navigate your view controller in main thread using below code.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // do some background task
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // update UI here
        // navigate your view controllers
        let vc: UIViewController =  (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewContIdentifire"))!
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                           // **OR**
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

      });
);
```

Navigate back to VC in more convenient way using

```
// using this navigate your app to root view of ui stack
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

// using this line of code navigate to any view        
self.navigationController?.popToViewController(viewContName, animated: true)

// this navigate back to last view
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Comment: The problem is that I work with different navigationControllers and some get closed with the so I would still have to find the last opened view somehow.

Comment: use `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)` it will brings the back option.

Comment: just apply with above code i have posted then you will understand how to navigate.

Comment: As I wrote in comment for answer below this one, I'm not making this call in a UIViewController class so I cant call self, that is my problem.
And also I can't set a parent class at start call, because after the call parent class closes and the aplication waits for WS call result.